# jQuery function for all dropdowns with one class on one page

Tags: jquery, this, dropdown

I have a problem. I need the function below to work on divs with the same class separately. Now I have separate classes for basically the same thing :(

My code:

```
<div class="selectDiv type">
    <span class="selectDefaultType"></span>
    <select name="txtType" class="selectBoxType">
        <option class="defaultTextType">IZVĒLIES VEIDU</option>
        <option value="1">Bārs</option>
        <option value="2">Nav bārs</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="selectDiv place">
    <span class="selectDefaultPlace"></span>
    <select name="txtPlace" class="selectBoxPlace">
        <option class="defaultTextPlace">IZVĒLIES PILSĒTU</option>
        <option value="1">Abkhazia</option>
        <option value="2">Afghanistan</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>

var defaultTextPlace = $('.defaultTextPlace').text();
$('.selectDefaultPlace').text(defaultTextPlace);
$('.selectBoxPlace').on('change', function () {
    var defaultTextPlaceUpdated = $('.selectBoxPlace').find(":selected").text();
    $('.selectDefaultPlace').text(defaultTextPlaceUpdated);
});

var defaultTextType = $('.defaultTextType').text();
$('.selectDefaultType').text(defaultTextType);
$('.selectBoxType').on('change', function () {
    var defaultTextTypeUpdated = $('.selectBoxType').find(":selected").text();
    $('.selectDefaultType').text(defaultTextTypeUpdated);
});

</script>

<style>
.selectDiv {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url('narvesen/img/openSelect.jpg') no-repeat right #f0f0f0;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:'Arimo', sans-serif;
}

.selectDefaultPlace, .selectDefaultType {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:'Arimo', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.selectDiv select {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 101;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.selectDiv select:focus {
    outline: none;
}

</style>
```

[fiddle!!!](http://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/psmuaoy3/1/)

I am still learning jQuery so any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i think you you forgot to mention the error

Comment: I will have 10 dropdowns on one page. Right now I have to write a function for each of them because I don't know the best way to write one function for all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler way:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/psmuaoy3/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="selectDiv type">
    <span class="selectDefault"></span>
    <select class="selectBox">
        <option value="0">IZVĒLIES VEIDU</option>
        <option value="1">Bārs</option>
        <option value="2">Nav bārs</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="selectDiv place">
    <span class="selectDefault"></span>
    <select class="selectBox">
        <option value="0">IZVĒLIES PILSĒTU</option>
        <option value="1">Abkhazia</option>
        <option value="2">Afghanistan</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.selectBox').each(function(e){
    UpdateText($(this));
});

$('.selectBox').on('change', function () {
    UpdateText($(this));
});

function UpdateText(obj){
    var defaultTextUpdated = $(obj).find(":selected").text();  
    $(obj).parent().find('.selectDefault').text(defaultTextUpdated);

}
```

**CSS Update:**

```
.selectDefault {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: -25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family:'Arimo', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While your code is ok, you could compress it a little using `$.each`:

```
// look at all .selectDiv that have a select element and iterate over them separately...
$('.selectDiv select').each(function () {
    var select = $(this), // $(this) is the select in the current iteration
        defaultText = select.children().filter('[class]').filter(':first').text(), // get the first option, filter by class attribute
        label = select.siblings('span').filter(':first'); // a nicer way would be to give each span the same class like 'selectDefault' without Type or Place

    label.text(defaultText); // initially set the default text

    select.on('change', function () {
        var updated = select.val();
        label.text(updated);
    });
});
```

a nicer way than

```
defaultText = select.children().filter('[class]').filter(':first').text()
```

would be to give each `option` with the default text function the same class:

```
 <option class="defaultTextType defaultText">IZVĒLIES VEIDU</option>
 ...
 <option class="defaultTextPlace defaultText">IZVĒLIES PILSĒTU</option>
```

and then just type

```
defaultText = select.children('.defaultText').text(),
```

Comment: Why is the dropdown updating to 1, 2 and not the provided text? How to fix that? Also- thank you! :)

Comment: Got it. Value. Will change value. :) Thank you! Awesome!